# Which were the standard undergraduate electromagnetism textbooks before Griffiths?

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, education, history

I am curious about the books that were the standard undergraduate electromagnetism textbooks in the 1950s and 1960s before [Griffiths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Electrodynamics) took over in the 80s.
Any resource recommendation would be welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Purcell, I suppose? If I remember correctly, both Griffiths and Jackson credit Purcell (the person) for their understanding of electrodynamics.

Answer (score 1):

In 1960, in a US  BA physics course, we had:

"Electricity and magnetism", F.W. Sears (professor of physics at MIT), copyright 1946.

Answer (score 1):

My first college E&M course in 1967 was out of **Electromagnetic Fields And Waves** - Dale Corson and Paul Lorrain, copyright 1962.  I had to pay $12.00 for it new.  I still use it.  They have new editions since then.